# How to conditionally replace values with NA across multiple columns

Tags: r, replace, dplyr, na

I would like to replace outliers in each column of a dataframe with NA.

If for example we define outliers as being any value greater than 3 standard deviations from the mean I can achieve this *per variable* with the code below.

Rather than specify each column individually I'd like to perform the same operation on all columns of `df` in one call. Any pointers on how to do this?!

Thanks!

```
library(dplyr)
data("iris")
df <- iris %>% 
  select(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length)%>% 
  head(10) 

# add a clear outlier to each variable
df[1, 1:3] = 99

# replace values above 3 SD's with NA
df_cleaned <- df %>% 
  mutate(Sepal.Length = replace(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Length > (abs(3 * sd(df$Sepal.Length, na.rm = TRUE))), NA))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `mutate_all()`, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 mutate_all(funs(replace(., . > (abs(3 * sd(., na.rm = TRUE))), NA)))
```

Comment: Solved! I thought I'd tried mutate_all but it turns out I had my dots in the wrong places. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `base R`

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) replace(x, . > (abs(3 * sd(x, na.rm = TRUE))), NA))
```

---

or with `colSds` from `matrixStats`

```
library(matrixStats)
df[df > abs(3 * colSds(as.matrix(df), na.rm = TRUE))] <- NA
```